# Color disappearing from d3 app when I use Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js

In the [following prototype](http://sunnysideworks.nyc/d3/bubble/) (modifying a bl.ocks example), I've added text and links with the names of geographic regions. Originally everything was great but over the last few days I am seeing more and more black text and less colored text when I browse with Chrome. Firefox still works great. but in Chrome now I only see color on Africa and MiddleEast. Everything else is black (the text is black, the circles remain properly colored). Does anyone have any idea why this would be?

So here's what I see on Firefox (and what I used to see on Chrome just a few days ago):

[image: good]

and here's what I am now seeing with Chrome:

[image: bad]

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the difference?

Comment: @daramao have posted screenshots as requested. thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Try setting the color through `.style()` and not `.attr()`.

Comment: @sunny, I am seeing the colors fine in Chrome. The only thing I noticed is that you are filling the text in d3 (data join, I assume). Try giving the text a class and styling in your stylesheet instead.

Comment: @daramao thanks for the suggestion. I don't know css very well - is there an option where I wouldn't have to declare a separate class for each region so as to give each a different color? also how then can I relate the colors to the d3.color() used for the circles?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that but it did not make a difference in Chrome (even after clearing the browser cache).

Comment: What do you mean by `over the last few days`, are you interacting with the graph in some way?  Do you let it sit and the color changes?  Do you run the code from day to day and it produces different results?  There's more to this story then you are telling us.

Comment: @Mark I load the page in my browser from day to day, and every few days I notice more color missing from the list of regions,